# Ajax error when retrieving data from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send data to my PHP file which inserts values in DB (this part is OK) and then send back JSON encoded data to the JavaScript file so that I can display them but it is not working. I do not know what is really wrong. I've been looking at many working examples and mines are not working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "requete.php", 
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
       alert('error');
    }
});
```

Data is correctly sent to PHP and inserted in DB but the following json won't display :

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'add_attribution') {


 $nom = $_POST['nom'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $montant = (int)$_POST['montant'];
 $type = utf8_decode($_POST['type']); 

    $sql = "insert into bo_depenses (montant,date,personne,description,carte) values('$montant','$date','','$nom','$type')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'Success message: hooray!');

    echo json_encode($data);
```

With this code, the console returns "Object" with the data sent to PHP/MySql ( ?? )

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE** : I managed to get the json result by putting in the error:

```
  var obj = JSON.stringify(data)
  alert(obj);
```

It turns out that it displays the first values I sent to my PHP script (to insert in DB) and not the one I JSON encoded... Why ?

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` at the beginning of your success function: what gets logged into [your browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? This will tell you 1) whether the call succeeded, and 2) what the full response was. Update your question to show what you found. Alternatively use the Network tab of the console: does the request to `requete.php` succeed, and post the full response into your question.

Comment: try using `if (data.success == 'true'){`. php might make this into a string.

Comment: what does `requete.php` actually return?

Comment: make sure there is no extraneous output in the php and that absolutly the only thing returned is the `json_encode`. WHat is value of `errorThrown`?

Comment: Is it entering the `Success` block of ur ajax call ?

Comment: @charlietfl If in run the PHP script manually I have the JSON output correctly (with $_GET instead of $_POST) but still not working on the JS side

Comment: @charlietfl errorThrown alert displays "Object object"

Comment: log object to console

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if ($.trim(data.success) == 1)
```

sometimes back i have faced the simillar situation ad i solved that using this

Comment: Thanks but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Put `header("content-type: application/json");` before **`echo`**.

Comment: ok, try to change your success if  to `if (data.success) {...}`. And maybe delete `dataType: "json"`